# Unable to access predefined images and functions from external HTML files I've imported using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want your support so solve the following issue:

In a webpage, I have a JavaScript script where I declared and loaded and array of images:

```
 function LoadPicts() { 
  "use strict";
  var rut1 = "./ima/ijpg/"; 
  var i = 0;
  for (i =0; i < 3; i++) {
     aimagen[i] = new Image();
  }
  aimagen[0].src  = rut1 + "info-logo.jpg";
  aimagen[1].src  = rut1 + "info-rollo.jpg";
  aimagen[2].src  = rut1 + "loading.jpg"; 
 }
```

Using .load jQuery, I used .load to import content form and external html file an put it inside a div called "Rconte":

```
$("#Rconte").load("Op100.html");
```

Op100.html has the following information:

```
  <table>
      <tr><td class = "pt4"><img src= "aimagen[21].src" onclick="DespLogo()"></td></tr>
      <tr><td class = "pt4"><img src= "aimagen[22].src" onclick="DespLogo()"></td>
  </table>
```

Why I cannot access aimagen[21] and aimagen[22] if they already have been loaded and I'm only referring to them? The same happened with function DespLogo().

Concerning the images, I received a Firebug error message::Failed to load the given URL"
Concerning the function DespLogo(), Firebug is telling me that the function has not been defined.

My general question would be: What should I focus on in order to bring new content to my Webpage from external files (html, txt, etc.) which need to access objects and functions that have been already declared?

Thanks!

Comment: Are your HTML and JS file in the same directory?

Comment: Hi Leo. The src of the images have already been defined in the array, I only need that the references to aimagen[21] and aimagen[22] work. Why is working fine if, instead of importing Op100.html, I put the same information inside a string (eg called stempo) and then into the div container using $(#Rconte).html(stempo)?

Comment: Oops, I saw your updated code. Obviously it's not working. `<img src= "aimagen[21].src" onclick="DespLogo()">` is parsed as HTML, it's not JavaScript. It is trying to find this file `./aimagen[21].src`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I looks that I still have a lot to learn..lol